# firebird Linux Terminal ExceptionStatement failed, SQLSTATE = 08006

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

firebird 2.5
Could not connect firebird db [image]
What would you recommend?
what should I do?

Comment: Have you verified that Firebird server is running on localhost?

Comment: Yes I am resolved, *.dbf  not permission. And used chown Thanks.